# jQuery.Deferred() / Promises functionality in GWT?

Tags: jquery, gwt, promise, jquery-deferred, gwtquery

Recently, I've discovered I **really** like [jQuery.Deferred()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) and the features it gives you to handle asynchronous flow control ([Promises](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises)).  I suppose the things I like the most ar the callback hooks for an Ajax request (`.done()` and `.fail()` ) and ability to `.resolve()` and `.reject()` a promise.  I might need this functionality at some point for a [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/) project and I was wondering, is there anything analogous in that ecosystem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[gwtquery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) 1.4.0 implements Deferred in the same way jquery does:

- They are Based on the CommonJS Promises/A+ spec
- The gQuery implementation is inspired in the jQuery API.
- And gQuery promises are MVP compliant, so as they can be run in the JVM.

Recently, we have given a gwtquery presentation in the [GWT.create Conference](http://gwtcreate.com/) introducing new stuff like promises, you can take a look to the [slides](http://gwtquery.github.io/gwt.create-slides/slides/gwtcreate.html#18) (push arrow keys to move between slides).

`ajax()` now returns a `Promise`, you can as well get the `promise()` associated with the queue of any gQuery object. Additionally you can create `Deferred()` in any gwt callback or use helper functions to deal with RequestBuider, RPC, RF.

Taken from the junit tests, here you have a portion of code of how can you use them in your code:

```
  public void testDeferredAjaxWhenDone() {
    String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/user_id/posts/post_id?callback=?&key=NO-KEY";

    delayTestFinish(5000);
    GQuery.when(Ajax.getJSONP(url))
      .done(new Function() {
        public void f() {
          Properties p = arguments(0);
          assertEquals(400, p.getProperties("error").getInt("code"));
          finishTest();
        }
      });
  }

  public void testDeferredAjaxWhenFail() {
    String url1 = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/user_id/posts/post_id?callback=?&key=NO-KEY";
    String url2 = "https://localhost:4569/foo";

    delayTestFinish(5000);
    GQuery.when(
     Ajax.getJSONP(url1), 
     Ajax.getJSONP(url2))
      .done(new Function() {
        public void f() {
          fail();
        }
      })
      .fail(new Function(){
        public void f() {
          finishTest();
        }
      });
  }

  int progress = 0;
  public void testPromiseFunction() {
    delayTestFinish(3000);
    final Promise doSomething = new PromiseFunction() {
      @Override
      public void f(final Deferred dfd) {
        new Timer() {
          int count = 0;
          public void run() {
            dfd.notify(count ++);
            if (count > 3) {
              cancel();
              dfd.resolve("done");
            }
          }
        }.scheduleRepeating(50);
      }
    };

    doSomething.progress(new Function() {
      public void f() {
        progress = arguments(0);
      }
    }).done(new Function() {
      public void f() {
        assertEquals(3, progress);
        assertEquals(Promise.RESOLVED, doSomething.state());
        finishTest();
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

I've just open-sourced [Promises for Java](https://github.com/tbroyer/promises) inspired by the CommonJS Promises/A+ proposal and Dart's Futures.

My goal is to add GWT support soon (GWT compatibility for `Promises` and `FulfillablePromise`, and helpers for, at least, GWT-RPC).

Comment: Nice!  I'll give it a try soon :)

Comment: throyer/promises has been deprecated. Any guidance on where to go?

Comment: gwtquery or JsInterop